# Deadlock is not detected with Java

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I am a Java newbie, and I have been trying to learn about multithreading, and its usage. Within multi threading, I am trying to understand deadlocks and wrote a program to do so. The issue is that the conditional deadlock method still returns `false` which means no deadlock is detected. I hope that someone can help.

This is my program to generate a deadlock.

```
public class DeadlockGenerator {
    private Object firstLockObject = new Object();
    private Object secondLockObject = new Object();

    public void generateDeadlock() {
      Thread threadOne = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
          synchronized(firstLockObject) {
            System.out.println("Thread1 on first lock object");
            synchronized(secondLockObject) {
              System.out.println("Thread2 on second lock object");
            }
          }
        }
      });
      threadOne.start();

      Thread threadTwo = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
          synchronized(secondLockObject) {
            System.out.println("Thread2 on second lock object");
            synchronized(firstLockObject) {
              System.out.println("Thread1 on first lock object");
            }
          }
        }
      });
      threadTwo.start();
      try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
  }
```

This is my program to detect deadlocks

```
  public class DeadlockThread  {

    private final ThreadMXBean bean;

    DeadlockThread(ThreadMXBean bean) {
      this.bean = bean;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the the number of dead locked threads.
     * @return number of deadlocked threads
     */
    public int numberOfDeadlockedThreads() {
      long [] deadlockThreadIds = this.bean.findMonitorDeadlockedThreads();
      return deadlockThreadIds == null ? 0 : deadlockThreadIds.length;
    }
   }
```

This is my function to invoke a both deadlock and the detection.

```
  /**
   * Initiates a deadlock and checks if it still exists after {@code timeInSeconds} have elapsed.
   * 
   * @param timeInSeconds time in seconds
   * @return {@code true} if deadlock is detected; {@code false} otherwise
   */
  static boolean startAndDetectDeadlocks(int timeInSeconds) {
    new DeadlockGenerator().generateDeadlock();
    try {
      Thread.sleep(timeInSeconds * 1000);
      ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
      DeadlockThread dt = new DeadlockThread(bean);
      return dt.numberOfDeadlockedThreads() > 0;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Upon debugging, I noticed the following issue. The following line of code

```
long [] deadlockThreadIds = this.bean.findMonitorDeadlockedThreads();
```

always returns `null`.

I don't know what I am doing wrong, and I appreciate any assistance in this matter.

Comment: This code might create deadlock but is not guaranteed to do so. If one of the threads finishes execution even before the other one starts (possible because the locking code is too simple), you won't have a deadlock. Maybe you could try invoking this hundreds of times in a loop. Or have more complicated processing after aquiring lock.

Comment: Or try moving the two `threadXXX.start()` calls immediately next to each other. Right now, in the time it takes to create Thread object and assign to threadTwo, threadOne might complete.

Answer (score 1):

`findMonitorDeadlockedThreads` method - returns an array of IDs of the threads that are monitor deadlocked, if any; null otherwise.

I guess there is no deadlock situation happening here, thread1 completes and exits before thread2 starts running.

Try to put some sleep time inside the thread 1 after acquiring `firstLockObject`. So that Thread 2 get a chance to run and acquire `secondLockObject`.

```
Thread threadOne = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(firstLockObject) {
                System.out.println("Thread1 on first lock object");
                try {
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex){
                     // do nothing...
                }
                synchronized(secondLockObject) {
                    System.out.println("Thread2 on second lock object");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

After this change the numberOfDeadlockedThreads returns as 2.